# UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character

Tags: python

Хочу построчно считать пути из файла 'feautures_90.txt', по которым будут открыты файлы .csv и собраны построчно в один файл 'feautures.csv'. Появляется ошибка кодировки.
Как победить? Кодировки указал везде, где только можно, но ничего не выходит.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd


def toFeaturesAnomalies(line):
    df = pd.read_csv(line, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

    num_det = str(line[line.find('det_')+4:line.find('.csv')])
    num_def = str(line[line.find('defect№_')+8:line.find('_time_')])

    df = df.drop('row', 1).rename({'detector_' + num_det: 'A_' + num_def + '_' + num_det}, axis=1)
    tf = df.T

    with open('feautures.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        tf.to_csv(f, header=False, encoding='utf-8')


with open('feautures_90.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
            print(line)
            toFeaturesAnomalies(line)

Ошибка: 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Working\ML\Трещины CD\Train_data\DataForML\txt_csv.py", line 22, in <module>
    toFeaturesAnomalies(line)
  File "D:\Working\ML\Трещины CD\Train_data\DataForML\txt_csv.py", line 7, in toFeaturesAnomalies
    df = pd.read_csv(line, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 686, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character
```

Comment: Добавьте трассу стека, чтобы было видно весь путь вызовов

Comment: и кусок данных из файла, на которые ругается интерпретатор.

Comment: Не пойму на какой файл интерпретатор ругается

Comment: @СергейЕршов выводите в цикле имя открываемого файла. Сделайте мини-дебагинг.

Comment: Попытался вывести одну строку файла "feautures_90.txt".

Comment: Так мы ничего не поймем. Хотя бы начало первого файла из списка в feautures_90.txt приведите

Comment: @strawdog В файле  feautures_90.txt только пути к файлам .csv. "D:/Working/ML/Трещины CD/Train_data/DataForML/1037088/CD90_18/CD90_18_defect№_1037088_time_60_75_det_224.csv
D:/Working/ML/Трещины CD/Train_data/DataForML/1038916/CD90_18/CD90_18_defect№_1038916_time_40_60_det_85.csv
D:/Working/ML/Трещины CD/Train_data/DataForML/1038916/CD90_18/CD90_18_defect№_1038916_time_45_60_det_84.csv
D:/Working/ML/Трещины CD/Train_data/DataForML/1040140/CD90_18/CD90_18_defect№_1040140_time_45_55_det_178.csv и т.д."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную проблему получилось решить следующим образом:

```
import pandas as pd


with open('feautures_90.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():

        df = pd.read_csv(line.rstrip('\n'))
        num_det = str(line[line.find('det_')+4:line.find('.csv')])
        num_def = str(line[line.find('defect№_')+8:line.find('_time_')])
        df = df.drop('row', 1).rename({'detector_' + num_det: 'A_' + num_def + '_' + num_det}, axis=1)
        tf = df.T

        with open('feautures.csv', 'a') as f:
            tf.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Правда, до сих пор не понял, что именно было причиной.